# How do I comunicate with my computer through Kivy?

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I would like to know if it's possible to create a Kivy app that can communicate with my computer. I want to be able to click a button in my Kivy App (thats installed in my smartphone) and trigger the execution of  another python script. For example, I would click a button in my smartphone and a Python code in my Windows PC prints "hello world".

Thanks guys. I really appreciate your help. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: you will have to create server on PC which can receive information from smartphone. It can be HTTP/WWW server or other. You could use Flask framework to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a server, like Flask. Install flask with `pip install flask`.

Then, write a simple server. The code is going to write messages sent by client to `messages.log` file. Of course, you could do something else, for example shutdown your PC.

server.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import time
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    try:
        message = request.form['message']
        return do_something(message)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return 'error'


def do_something(message):
    with open('messages.log', 'a') as f:
        current_time = time.ctime()
        f.write(current_time + ': ' + message + '\n')
    return 'message saved'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Run the file. The server's address is `http://localhost:5000`.

Once you have a working server, write a client app. The code will send a text message to the server.

test.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

MainLayout:
    cols: 1
    spacing: '30dp'
    padding: '50dp', '50dp', '50dp', '50dp'

    Label:
        id: status_label
        size_hint_y: 0.3

    TextInput:
        id: message_input

    Button:
        text: 'send message to server'
        on_press: root.send_message(message_input.text)

    Button:
        text: 'quit app'
        on_press: app.stop()
```

client.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import urllib


class MainLayout(GridLayout):

    count = 1

    def send_message(self, message):
        POST_data = self._prepare_data(message)
        self._send_message(POST_data)

    def _prepare_data(self, message):
        auth_data = {'message': message}
        auth_data = urllib.urlencode(auth_data)
        headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        return {'auth_data': auth_data, 'headers': headers}

    def _send_message(self, POST_data):
        UrlRequest(
            url='http://localhost:5000/',
            req_body=POST_data['auth_data'],
            req_headers=POST_data['headers'],
            on_failure=self._on_connection_failure,
            on_error=self._on_connection_error,
            on_success=self._on_connection_success,
        )

    def _on_connection_success(self, request, result):
        self.ids.status_label.text =\
            'message %s delivered' % self.count
        self.count += 1

    def _on_connection_failure(self, request, result):
        self.ids.status_label.text = 'connection fail'

    def _on_connection_error(self, request, result):
        self.ids.status_label.text = 'connection error'


class Test(App):
    pass


Test().run()
```

To connect to the server with your smartphone, then as URL in UrlRequest type the computer's ip address instead of 'localhost', for example: `http://192.168.0.1:5000/`.

Comment: @AlejandroDapenaSanz Please mark my post as an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks man but, in which order do I have to run the codes, also, kivy code it says bad syntax ... :/

Comment: @AlejandroDapenaSanz Run server.py and client.py; test.kv is used by client.py.